# In Django, what does {%- and -%} mean in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

For the life of me, I cannot find this either here or in the official Django docs. What does adding `-` after `{%` and before `%}` in a Django template tag mean? Here's an example:

`{% if database -%}{{ database.name }}{%- else -%}blah{%- endif %}`

Comment: Where did you found these?

Comment: https://djlint.com/docs/best-practices/

Comment: I think this might be some site formatting gone wrong, the `^ space here` is also placed at the wrong column, so might have been something JavaScript should use as a "hint" but has failed to pick up.

Comment: Good to know. Like I said, I couldn't find it anywhere else but wanted to ask.

Comment: I've added an issue to their GitHub repo https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/djLint/issues/713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphens have nothing to do with Django itself. My guess is that these should be used to hint the code formatted to format these properly.

The reason that this is likely is because if we look a the [source code of the documentation <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/djLint/blob/master/docs/src/docs/best-practices.md?plain=1#L15-L22), we see:

> ````
> {% raw %}
>
> ```html
> <div class="class1 {% if condition -%}class2{%- endif %}">content</div>
> ^ space here
> ```
>
> {% endraw %}
> ````

The `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` are used for the rendering engine of the documentation itself. Likely the hyphen is used to prevent the render engine from *interpreting* the template tags we want to show as just code, so to prevent that `{% if condition %}` is interpreted itself.

But it looks like the formatted has done a bad job, and retained the hyphens, and thus the documentation shows some of the "mechanics" on how the documentation should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is Jinja2 templating syntax. The `-` is part of controlling how it deals with whitespace.
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/

From the docs:

> If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For
> tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or
> after that block will be removed

Comment: Do you have a link where it says this in the docs? I couldn't find it though I swear I thought I saw it mentioned somewhere. Though I may have been confusing it with another template engine.

Comment: It's Jinja2 syntax, which is included by optional. The standard Django templating engine has `{% spaceless %}` instead. Looking through the source if it also accepts the dash.